# ADO.NET обращение к таблицам по имена

Tags: c#, ado.net

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, когда я пытаюсь загрузить таблицу (или таблицы) из БД с помощью `DataSet и DataAdapter`, то у этих таблиц при загрузке по умолчанию имена `Table, Table1` и.т.д и следовательно я не могу обращаться к `DataSet.Tables` вводя в индекс имя таблицы, обращение идет лишь по номеру индекса, но в случае если у меня 15 таблиц, то как я могу узнать где и какая таблица и под каким номером ? И есть ли возможность, чтобы при загрузке сразу множества таблиц автоматически загружалось и их имя в базе данных, а не всякие `Table1` и пр. ? Код, который я использую (не грузит имена таблиц из БД):

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Users];select * from [Groups]", @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\sergey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Провайдер к MS SQL Server не предаёт имена таблиц. Да и смысла большого в этом нету.
Чтобы соотнести таблицы из запроса с таблицами в DataSet-е нужно описать в [DataAdapter.TableMappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) отношения между ними:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Users];select * from [Groups]", @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\sergey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Users");
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Groups");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Также объект типа [DataTableMappingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.datatablemappingcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) позволяет прописать отнашения по колонкам.